Why can't find resources namespace in Blazor Web App project?
The framework I am using is .Net 8
I want to follow these two tutorials to achieve ErrorMessage with different language.
Why can't I use resources as ErrorMessage with DataAnnotations?
Blazor WebAssembly Client DataAnnotations Localization
Here is the path of the resources file:

And I have set Access Modifier to public already:

What's more, I have set the resources file path in program.cs also:
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options=>options.ResourcesPath="Resources");     

However, when I code it like this:
 private sealed class InputModel
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageUserNameRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
     [EmailAddress]
     public string Email { get; set; } = "";

     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessagePasswordRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     public string Password { get; set; } = "";

     [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
     public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
 }

Visual Studio reports error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SharedResource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What's wrong with my code?

I think you need SharedResource.resx and SharedResource.zh-Hans.resx. The one file is the default and the other for chinese.
